# Rails checking if Time.zone.now is between 2 record times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my query to retrieve records of my **event** model is not working.

I'm trying to check if **current datetime** `Time.zone.now` is between `Event.startdate` and `Event.enddate` to show Live events in the view:

```
@online_event = Event.where("? BETWEEN startdate AND enddate", Time.zone.now)
```

It will turn to **false**, and won't return any events even if the current time is between their start and end dates.

**View**

```
<% if @online_event.count > 1 %>
  <%= @online_event.first.name %>
<% else %>
   No live events
<% end %>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're using variables in your SQL query. Try this: `@online_event = Event.where("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now, startdate, enddate)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting the error "undefined local variable or method `startdate' for #<PagesController:0x007fe64d2bfcd8>"

Comment: Do you have a startdate attribute on your pages table?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Event.where("startdate >= t AND enddate <= ?", t: Time.zone.now)
```